# CORS errors with Flask and gevent

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cors, gevent

I have an API running, using Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, and Flask-Restless, and am trying to make POST/PUT/DELETE requests from javascript (backbone.js, to be precise).  However, I keep running into CORS errors - everything except GET returns an HTTP OPTIONS 501 Not Implemented Error in the browser.

Initially, I tried adding the least restrictive CORS headers possible to all responses:

```
@app.after_request
def after(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
                         'POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                         'Content-Type, X-Requested-With')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Max-Age', '1728000')

    return response
```

CORS seemed to fail when the request's Content-Type header was set to application/json (as required by the API), so a quick hack was made to get things working:

```
@app.before_request
def before():
    request.environ['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/json'
```

However, everything except POST still fails.  Also, gevent's logging is turned on, but no OPTIONS requests are ever logged (which I believe is the CORS preflight stuff), even when the browser shows them failing with a 501.

Do I need to change something in gevent or Flask to get CORS working?

**Edit:**  Running the API using the built-in Flask server works, so gevent is the problem here, but I can't seem to find much in the way of docs...

Answer (score 7):

There is a flask snippet [Decorator for the HTTP Access Control](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/), you can use @crossdomain(origin='*') decorator.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use **flask-cors** plugin

Install using pip

> pip install -U flask-cors

Sample Code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/api/v1/users")
def list_users():
  return "user example"
```

For documentationh head over here [flask-cors documentation](http://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/index.html).